# Traffic Problem - ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, traffic

I am using (Ubuntu server) as a router, I have more traffic than (1 Giga) when I pass the traffic it decreases to about 400Mbps and when I run (bmon) it shows a "Core dumped" message.

I only get 500Mbps from 1Gbps, the question is why am I only getting this. When I first plugged it in I got 950 Mbps and then it dropped right down to around 500 Mbps. Also why does "segmentation fault (Core dumped)" message appear when I run bmon program.

This image is from web interface, what i get from bandwidth is dark blue misleading only.

[image: Sending and receiving bandwidth]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: For correction I only get 500Mbps from 1Gbps, the question is why am I only getting this.
When I first plugged it in I got 950 Mbps and then it dropped right down to around 500 Mbps.
Also why does "segmintation fault (Core dumped)" message appear when I run bmon program
This image is from web interface, what i get from bandwidth is dark blue misleading only

Comment: Add the info to the question with edit not as a comment.

Comment: where is problem?